# Debugging a SIGSEGV crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, segmentation-fault

Users have been reporting a SIGSEGV crash that I'm having great difficulty reproducing - it happens relatively often for them, but I've never been able to reproduce it. From reading other StackOverflow posts, I know I'm supposed to turn NSZombies on to find the zombie object, but no matter what I do in Instruments I can't get any zombies to show up.

Note that I am using ARC.

Can anyone make any sense out of these two crash reports so I at least know where to start looking for the zombie? And does anyone have any tips on how to get the zombie to show up in Instruments? Thanks!

Crash report #1:

```
0 MyApp 0x000e4972 testflight_backtrace + 238
1 MyApp 0x000e565c TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x31cd37ec _sigtramp + 48
3 UIKit 0x33e47bde -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 250
4 UIKit 0x33f8f498 -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 64
5 Foundation 0x37f264fe __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 18
6 CoreFoundation 0x376c8546 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 70
7 CoreFoundation 0x37654096 _CFXNotificationPost + 1406
8 Foundation 0x37e9a3ea -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
9 Foundation 0x37e9bc1a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
10 UIKit 0x33f5a270 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 80
11 UIKit 0x33f5a36a -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 174
12 libdispatch.dylib 0x349572e0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 516
13 libdispatch.dylib 0x34954b80 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 52
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x34954ec0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 156
15 CoreFoundation 0x376cf2ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
16 CoreFoundation 0x376524a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
17 CoreFoundation 0x3765236c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
18 GraphicsServices 0x3255f438 GSEventRunModal + 136
19 UIKit 0x33dd6e7c UIApplicationMain + 1080
20 MyApp 0x0001b65e main (main.m:16)
21 MyApp 0x000115af start + 39
```

Crash report #2:

```
0 MyApp 0x0018e972 testflight_backtrace + 238
1 MyApp 0x0018f65c TFSignalHandler + 264
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x31d067ec _sigtramp + 48
3 UIKit 0x33e7abde -[UIViewController unloadViewForced:] + 250
4 UIKit 0x33fc2498 -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 64
5 MyApp 0x000ec988 -[MyTableController didReceiveMemoryWarning] (MyTableController.m:129)
6 MyApp 0x0010a8a8 -[FeaturedViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] (FeaturedViewController.m:65)
7 Foundation 0x37f594fe __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 18
8 CoreFoundation 0x376fb546 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 70
9 CoreFoundation 0x37687096 _CFXNotificationPost + 1406
10 Foundation 0x37ecd3ea -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66
11 Foundation 0x37ecec1a -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 30
12 UIKit 0x33f8d270 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 80
13 UIKit 0x33f8d36a -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 174
14 libdispatch.dylib 0x3498a2e0 _dispatch_source_invoke + 516
15 libdispatch.dylib 0x34987b80 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 52
16 libdispatch.dylib 0x34987ec0 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 156
17 CoreFoundation 0x377022ac __CFRunLoopRun + 1268
18 CoreFoundation 0x376854a4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
19 CoreFoundation 0x3768536c CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
20 GraphicsServices 0x32592438 GSEventRunModal + 136
21 UIKit 0x33e09e7c UIApplicationMain + 1080
22 MyApp 0x000c565e main (main.m:16)
23 MyApp 0x000bb5af start + 39
```

Comment: It's almost impossible to tell from just a backtrace. The root cause of a segmentation violation can be in totally unrelated code. It double-frees a pointer or overwrites a buffer, and this leaves a time bomb that goes off some time later. And even if it is in the code, in the stack trace, we can't tell what it could be without seeing the source code.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Unfortunately my app is thousands upon thousands of lines of code. Any ideas on how to force this to show up on one of my devices, or in the simulator?

Comment: I wasn't actually suggesting that you post it. This is not really something we're likely to be able to help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like something is being done wrong when your app receives a memory warning. You can force this to happen on the simulator using the debug menu, or on the device by sending the (illegal in production code) `_performMemoryWarning` method:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] _performMemoryWarning];
```

You can put this on a repeating timer to regularly send the warnings. I'd advise wrapping this in an `#IFDEF DEBUG` to prevent it making it into production.

This won't solve your problem, but it may help you to reproduce the crash, which is the vital first step.

Comment: That would at least explain why it's happening on older devices, and not on my iPhone 5. I'll look into that, thanks!